# Movie/film where a family and friends are trapped on a beach that speeds up time

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've recently saw an ad on YouTube that showed a movie/TV series/film, I don't know if it's even a movie or not.

It first showed a family enjoying a nice afternoon on the beach. Their five-year-old son got lost, so they went to search for him. The son then came back as a grown man after a few minutes/hours of searching. There was also a scene where one of the girls got pregnant; things sped up for her too.

Sorry for not giving much information, since I accidentally skipped the ad. Is this a movie? Since I've been searching for good thriller movies to watch. If this movie exists, what is it called? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you saw a trailer for M. Night Shyamalan's upcoming film, *[Old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_(film))* (2021).

It features everything you mentioned: the family and friends on the beach, the boy who disappears and returns as a man, and something strange happening to a pregnant woman.

Comment: Yes! That is it! Thank you! I'll mark this as correct as soon as the system lets me (in about 4 minutes).